# Compare more than 2 arrays

Tags: javascript

What is a good algorithm to compare an array of an arbitrary number of arrays. There are a lot of stuff on the internet for comparing 2 arrays but not for an arbitrary number of arrays. For example, the following array of arrays

```
[ [5, 10, 15, 20], [15, 88, 1, 5, 7], [1, 10, 15, 5, 20] ]
```

I tried the following code to it does not work. Trying to understand conceptually how I should be going about it.

```
function compareTwoArrays(a, b) {
  let output = [];
  if (a.length <= b.length) {
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
       for (let j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
         if (a[i] === b[j]) {
           output.push(a[i]);
         }
       }
    }
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
       for (let j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
         if (b[i] === a[j]) {
           output.push(b[i]);
         }
       }
    }
  }
  return output;
}

function intersection(arr) {
  let output = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      if (arr[i][j].contains(arr[0][j])) {
        console.log(arr[i][j]);
      }
    }
  }

}
const arr1 = [5, 10, 15, 20];
const arr2 = [15, 88, 1, 5, 7];
const arr3 = [1, 10, 15, 5, 20];
console.log(intersection([arr1, arr2, arr3]));
```

Comment: You want to compare with what? You want the intersection of multiple arrays? Do you realise that the intersection(A, B, C) == intersection(intersection(A, B), C), so that you can solve this easily with any correct algorithm for two arrays?

Comment: Is the array only two dimensional? Or can it become three dimensional? As far as I know, there isn't any specific algorithm for comparing several arrays at once other than nested for loops for each array. This will make your program very slow however

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a correct algorithm for the intersection of two arrays (lets call it `intersect`) then you can easily use this function to get the intersection of more than two arrays. Just take the intersection of the first two. Then take the intersection of that result with the third array. Then use that result for an intersection with the fourth array, ...etc. This is typically what a *reducer* does:

```js
// Let's assume you have a correct pair-wise intersect function. 
//    It could be this one, or any other correct implementation:
function intersect(a, b) {
  return a.filter(function (v) {
    return this.has(v);
  }, new Set(b));
}

// ...then you only need this to generalise it:
const multiIntersect = arrays => arrays.reduce(intersect);

// Demo
const arr1 = [5, 10, 15, 20];
const arr2 = [15, 88, 1, 5, 7];
const arr3 = [1, 10, 15, 5, 20];
console.log(multiIntersect([arr1, arr2, arr3]));
```

Comment: Thank you trincot. Very elegant solution.